# Unable to use Managed Identity for Azure resources with local account

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-managed-identity

I've created an Azure SQL Database on my Azure subscription, and I'm trying to use a managed identity approach.
The `DbConnection` looks like this:

```
Server=tcp:server-name.database.windows.net,1433; Database=DB Dev; Authentication=Active Directory Default; TrustServerCertificate=True;
```

And for the other resources (Cognitive Search and Service Bus), I did the following configuration :

```
services.AddAzureClients(clientBuilder =>
{
    clientBuilder
        .AddServiceBusClientWithNamespace(serviceBusFullyQualifiedNamespace)
        .WithName(serviceBusClientName);

    clientBuilder.AddSearchClient(
            new Uri(searchServiceEndpoint),
            "idx-name",
            new AzureKeyCredential(queryApiKey))
        .WithName(searchServiceClientName);

    // Use DefaultAzureCredential by default
    clientBuilder.UseCredential(new DefaultAzureCredential());
});
```

In Visual Studio, I'm logged in with the same Azure account where I have the resources but when I start the app, I get the following errors:

```
Azure.Identity[3]
      EnvironmentCredential.GetToken was unable to retrieve an access token. Scopes: [ https://database.windows.net//.default ] ParentRequestId:  Exception: Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException (0x80131500): EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot

Azure.Core[18]
      Request [d62d1dff-e775-4a43-a276-17658251e040] exception System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was cancelled because it exceeded the configured timeout of 0:00:01. Network timeout can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry.NetworkTimeout.
       ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
         at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.HandleFailure(Exception e, Boolean telemetryStarted, HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationTokenSource cts, CancellationToken cancellationToken, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
         at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpClientTransport.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, Boolean async)
         at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineTransportPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)         at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RequestActivityPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
         at Azure.Core.Pipeline.ResponseBodyPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Azure.Core.Pipeline.ResponseBodyPolicy.ThrowIfCancellationRequestedOrTimeout(CancellationToken originalToken, CancellationToken timeoutToken, Exception inner, TimeSpan timeout)
         at Azure.Core.Pipeline.ResponseBodyPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
         at Azure.Core.Pipeline.LoggingPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)

ManagedIdentityCredential.GetToken was unable to retrieve an access token. Scopes: [ https://database.windows.net//.default ] ParentRequestId:  Exception: Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException (0x80131500): ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Multiple attempts failed to obtain a token from the managed identity endpoint
         
Azure.Identity[10]
      False MSAL 4.49.1.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 6.0.15 Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045 [2023-04-16 07:34:32Z - eb2dde69-b2de-48e6-b48c-2d01cd1adc66] Exception type: Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException
      ---> Inner Exception Details
      Exception type: System.AggregateException
      ---> Inner Exception Details
      Exception type: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException
      ---> Inner Exception Details
      Exception type: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException
```

Since I'm the subscription owner, I can't understand why I'm unable to log in using the Visual Studio account. Should I do some extra configurations?

For the Azure SQL Database, I've created a user for the Admins Group (and I've included also myself) and I've whitelisted my IP in the firewall configuration.

Comment: did you consult: https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot, like the error suggests?

Comment: Yes. But for the local setup, I don't have any AZURE_CLIENT_ID. And as I understood, this is for System assigned managed identity (to create an App registration), but I want to use a User assigned managed identity.

Comment: system and user assigned identities work the same way, you manage them differently.

Comment: Ok, but what do I have to do in order to allow my local application to communicate with the database using the account that I'm logged in with in Visual Studio?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16#using-active-directory-default-authentication